# Why didn't the rebelling Cylons just box the other models?

Tags: plot-explanation, battlestar-galactica

I was re-watching BSG this week, and saw the episode where the rebelling Cylon models wipe out the others, to stop them from lobotomizing the Raiders (by giving the Centurions the gift of reason).

However, they don't go any further and allow the other models to resurrect and wreak their vengeance upon their fleet of baseships, causing them to be whittled down to just the one heavily-damaged baseship.

Why didn't the rebelling models box all the other lines to ensure no more resurrection could happen before trying to carry out the rest of their plans to stop the raider lobotomization and then find the final five? Seems like that would've saved them all the loss and headache. Then they could've joined the Colonials with three complete baseships instead of 75% of one.

Comment: I would need to rewatch the episode you are referring to, to get my facts straight, but I think that the Cavil-side controlled the boxing facility and/or possibly Cavil may be the only one who knows how to box, because In the Final Five comic book, it's revealed he was made in image of Ellen's father and he was designed to be a biological engineer, and created first, to help the final five finish resurrection technology. If I can find subsequent evidence I will come back and answer.

Comment: It's also worth noting that we don't know how the actual boxing process works. Does it require unanimous agreement (except for those being boxed) or can one model box another arbitrarily. I'd suggest the former is more likely.